# a function that gives it system call number and return its name

Tags: c++, c, linux, x86-64, system-calls

is there any function in c or c++ which we give system call number as argument and it returns us system call name? for example we give it 60 and it returns exit. for linux x86_64 system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a lookup table from your system's glibc header files, like this perl one-liner:

```sh
perl -nE '
  BEGIN { say "const char *syscallnames[] = {" }
  if (/__NR_(\w+) (\d+)/) { say qq/\t[$2] = "$1",/ }
  END { say "};" }' /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h > syscallnames.h
```

The exact location of `asm/unistd_64.h` might vary depending on your distribution and glibc version. This was on Ubuntu.

And use it with something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const char * scnum_to_name(int num) {
#include "syscallnames.h"
  return syscallnames[num];
}
  
int main(void) {
  int num = 60;
  printf("%d = %s\n", num, scnum_to_name(num));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh it's very easy. it's fantastic. thank you so much. thank you. thank you

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any standard library function.  This is functionality that very few applications would need.  But you could borrow a table from someone who already wrote one, e.g. [this table](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/linux/x86_64/syscallent.h) from `strace(1)`, assuming of course that you will comply with its copyright license.

Comment: it's great. thanks so much. but how should i use that?

Comment: Maybe simplest just to delete the stuff you don't care about, so it's just a long list of designated initializers like `[0] = "read", [1] = "write", ...`, and use it to initialize some `char *syscall_names[]`.  Then you can write `syscall_names[60]` and get `"exit"`.